# How to make digital signature of documents with blockchain?

Tags: python, digital-signature, blockchain

I am aiming to create a website that requires user to login, upload documents and sign them using [blockchain](https://blockchain.info/home) (**single sign or multiple signs**) just like [signatura](https://signatura.co/) or [blocksign](https://blocksign.com/).

I have seen both of the websites and have a little bit idea how they work. But it's the technical picture that I am not getting.

So as an intermediate python develop, I have some question. Please answer.

1. Overall flow from after uploading a document to my website before downloading if successfully signed by all parties (Technically).
2. How to generate private and public keys and Will I store them alongside user information?
3. How to interact to blockchain [api](https://blockchain.info/api). I already gone through the api but nothing make sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

Phew, you've set yourself a tough goal for someone new at blockchain. Still, it is quite doable. I am going to answer your questions out of order, because that is how the code flows.

> How to generate private and public keys and Will I store them alongside user information?

You should not be generating private keys. At the very least, use client-side code to generate them, if necessary. As for storage, you should not be storing them, either. Let the users store them client side, preferably in a dedicated wallet with an API like Metamask.

Unfortunately, your post implies that you mean the Bitcoin blockchain, and I'm not aware of any similar wallets with APIs for Bitcoin... Use the safest available Storage and encryption if you must, but whatever you do, do not send the private keys to the server.

> Overall flow from after uploading a document to my website before downloading if successfully signed by all parties (Technically).

OK, Lets follow an example document signing step by step.

1. A uploads document to your website.
2. B signs document w his private key.
3. B uploads signed document to your website.
4. Your website hashes the signed document.
5. Your website broadcasts a transaction with the signed document hash as metadata.

Now lets say A wants to verify that B signed the document.

1. A downloads B's signed copy of the document.
2. A hashes the signed document, and compares it to the hash you provide.
3. A checks the blockchain for the transaction that includes the document hash.

If all three steps succeed, A can now be certain that B signed the document around the time of the transaction being included in a block.

> How to interact to blockchain api. I already gone through the api but nothing make sense to me.

The normal blockchain.com API is not suitable for this use case. You do not have a fine enough control over the transaction content, which is needed to embed the document hashes.

I recommend you use a library like [python-bitcoinlib](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib) or [bitcoinlib-js](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib) to create the transaction, and use RPC to a node, to interact with the blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

Document storage on Blockchain may impact its performance and hence not always recommended from a scalability perspective. Hence it may be a better idea to store the document in a decentralized - distributed file system like IPFS ( Inter-Planetary File System ) and then pass the reference to a Blockchain platform like Ethereum. In Ethereum you can design and develop a Multi-Signature Wallet with Proof of Authority kind of consensus algorithm and invoke a collection of smart contracts that can help you to author, edit, version, publish, archive and expire the document in a secure and scalable manner. Hope it helps. Let me know if you need any further details on this approach.

Comment: Yes. I know that whole document would not go to blockchain only the hash will be sent as data. Can you provide some link or tutorial that help me understand this

Comment: Sure. I will share some tutorials on how we can implement this using Ethereum. Essentially you need to model each of these steps into either actions / transactions. Here signing into your application is an action. Document upload is another action. Validation of documents could be a transaction or a distributed process where the document is stored in a location that could be reviewed by various approvers. You could capture metadata about this document in the previous step. You could generate a public key about this document using the metadata itself.

Comment: can you share tutorial @GokulAlex ?

Comment: @AdilMalik, please find a reference implementation of Ethereum - IPFS based document storage example here >> https://github.com/howardwu/IPFS-Ethereum-Storage

Comment: @user305883 please refer the following medium article to build an Ethereum IPFS integration based Document Storage Dapp. https://itnext.io/build-a-simple-ethereum-interplanetary-file-system-ipfs-react-js-dapp-23ff4914ce4e